# Spring-boot logback and jboss 7.1.1 doesn't not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss7.x

I am working with spring-boot 1.3.5.RELEASE, but when I deploy my war file application in JBOSS 7.1.1, the file log is created but nothing is showed, the file is empty.

When I test the same configuration in Tomcat the log is showed. Any idea why it doesn't work in Jboss? Thanks.

My file logback.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- Log message format -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <!-- Ned appender to write to file -->
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <!-- Name of the file where the log messages are written -->
    <file>c:/satlogs/notifications.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <logger name="net.javabeat.service" level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="net.javabeat.model" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

  <!-- Setting the root level of logging to INFO -->
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />    
  </root>
</configuration>
```

My file application.properties

```
#DATASOURCE PRODUCTION
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/smartSATMySql

schedule.cron = 00 00 22 * * *

server.servlet-path=/*
```

My file pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pe.gob.sat</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartsatnotifications</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>smartsatnotification</name>
    <description>SmartSAT Notifications</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's transitive you don't have a dependency on logback. You'd also need to exclude the `org.slf4j` module, see the [log4j example](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) for details, from your deployment.